# how to automate electron exe file using protractor framework

Tags: testing, protractor

Please tell me in detail ..

I have an electron application and I have exe of that .. but want to automate using  protractor framework.

Guide me in that .

Comment: Hi Shyam have you cracked the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using Spectron

https://electronjs.org/spectron

Spectron is a testing tool for electron application. You can test it after packing into a exe file or straight away starting the test by mentioning the main.js

```
npm install --save-dev spectron
```

Install spectron via npm . Below example uses mocha for assertions.

To get up and running from your command line:

Install mocha locally as a dev dependency.

```
npm i mocha -D
```

create a spec file like below

```
const Application = require('spectron').Application
const assert = require('assert')
const electronPath = require('electron') 
const path = require('path')
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');


 global.before(() => {
     chai.should();
     chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
  });


describe('Application launch', function () {
  this.timeout(10000)

  beforeEach(function () {
     const opts = {
  path: './your.exe'
};
const app = new Application(opts);
return app.start().then((app) => {
  chaiAsPromised.transferPromiseness = app.transferPromiseness;
  return app;

      })
  })

  afterEach(function () {
    if (this.app && this.app.isRunning()) {
      return this.app.stop()
    }
  })

  it('shows an initial window', function () {
    return this.app.client.getWindowCount().then(function (count) {
      assert.equal(count, 1)
      // Please note that getWindowCount() will return 2 if `dev tools` are opened.
      // assert.equal(count, 2)
    })
  })
})
```

Run the test by:

```
mocha spec.js
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but I am given task to use protractor only. So tell me using that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440031/using-protractor-in-electron

Comment: Actually its not working that's why I reposted the question.

Comment: it launches the application but doesn' take spec file working .. it says chrome unreachable